# Comment @reply name suggestions are missing from review queues

Tags: bug, comments, review, comment-replies

Normally when I type a comment and type `@` followed by the first letters of the name of another commenter, there will be an autocomplete suggestion that I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to accept:

[image: Example screenshot showing the name being suggested from the first letter]

However, I have just noted that attempting to reply to someone **from within a review task**, no such suggestions are offered:

[image: No suggestion from within the queue]

I feel this bizarre inconsistency should be fixed. I could reproduce this on every queue I have tried, though the example screenshot is in Low Quality Answers.

Comment: Note that a while ago, comments used to not be allowed to be posted from the low quality review queue - a few years ago, they began to be allowed, but I think that script isn't loaded because it was a relatively recent change.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I reproduced this for other queues such as First Questions, First Answers, and Late Answers too.